Quarkus: Multiple SLF4j bindings found but can not be located
In my quarkus java application i get the following message from slf4j upon launch:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/.../quarkus-app/lib/main/org.jboss.slf4j.slf4j-jboss-logmanager-2.0.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/.../target/quarkus-app/lib/main/org.openpreservation.jhove.jhove-ext-modules-1.30.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: The requested version 2.0.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.

There seems to be a conflict between these two external dependencies in my pom (shortened here):
<dependency>
   groupId>org.openpreservation.jhove</groupId>
   <artifactId>jhove-ext-modules</artifactId>
   <version>1.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.amqphub.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-qpid-jms</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>


I have done a mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes="*.slf4j" to find an slf4j implmentation in jhove-ext-modules:
[INFO] +- org.openpreservation.jhove:jhove-ext-modules:jar:1.30.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.w3c:epubcheck:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:11.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.xmlresolver:xmlresolver:jar:4.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:jar:5.1.3:runtime
[INFO] |     |        \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:runtime - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:runtime - version managed from 1.7.36; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:runtime - version managed from 1.7.36; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |        \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:compile - version managed from 1.7.36; omitted for duplicate)


and added the following exlclude:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpreservation.jhove</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhove-ext-modules</artifactId>
            <version>${org.openpreservation.jhove.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

This did however not change the outcome. The other dependency qpid-jms contains a transitive dependency org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logmanager:jar:2.0.0. If i add an exclusion for this, then the app starts up normally. However i would like to keep this dependency for log output.
Any help or hints are appreciated.


add slf4j-api and logback-classic.
add exclusions in jhove-ext-modules and quarkus-qpid-jms.

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpreservation.jhove</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhove-ext-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.amqphub.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-qpid-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

I can test that my own code can output the log file through SLF4J and then logback.
But I don't have your relevant code using jhove-ext-modules or quarkus-qpid-jms, so I can't verify it. , jhove-ext-modules or quarkus-qpid-jms can input log normally.
This part must be verified by your own project.
